# Code Coverage for Backend code when running UI Automated tests

Tags: cypress, code-coverage, test-coverage, cypress-code-coverage

I ve a test automation suite in Cypress for testing a webapp. The webapp is developed using JS frameworks in the frontend and Java/C# in the backend. My requirement is to calculate code coverage for both fronend and backend code when running my cypress automated tests. We have libraries like Istanbul that does this job for fronend/UI code.

Now I want to know how to calculate the code coverage for the backend/API code when running our Cypress UI automation tests?